# Handling Nested Objects in a Multi-Page Form with Local Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a multi-page form for an app I am making. I created an `interface` to represent the inputs the user will enter:

```
export interface PlanEngineInputs {
    age: number
    annualIncome: number
    annualSpending: number
    networth: number

    inflationRate: number

    stocksAllocationRate: number
    bondsAllocationRate: number
    cashAllocationRate: number

    stocksReturnRate: number
    bondsReturnRate: number
    cashReturnRate: number

    withdrawalStrategy: WithdrawalStrategy

    incomeGrowthRate?: number
    retirementAge?: number
    maximumAge?: number
}
```

The inputs that the user enters in each page of the form are saved to two local storage objects, one for the raw inputs that they enter, and another for the formatted inputs. I am using local storage instead of state because the previous component (and thus the state itself) gets removed from the DOM whenever the user switches pages.

Here is an example page, it starts by fetching the data from local storage and putting that into the inputs. Whenever the user changes anything in the inputs it saved the updated model to localStorage (I am using react-hook-form):

```
export default function BasicInfoInputs() {
    const { register, setValue, watch } = useForm<Partial<PlanEngineInputs>>()

    useEffect(() => {
        loadLocalStorage(setValue)
    }, [])

    watch(inputs => {
        updateRawInputs(inputs as Partial<PlanEngineInputs>)
    })

    return (
        <>
            <InputWrapper
                placeholder='Age'
                icon={<MdPerson />}
                register={register('age')}
            />

            <InputWrapper
                placeholder='Annual Income'
                icon={<MdAttachMoney />}
                register={register('annualIncome')}
            />

            <InputWrapper
                placeholder='Annual Spending'
                icon={<MdAttachMoney />}
                register={register('annualSpending')}
            />

            <InputWrapper
                placeholder='Networth'
                icon={<MdAttachMoney />}
                register={register('networth')}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

I am using an `InputWrapper` component to help simplify duplicated code:

```
interface InputWrapperProps {
    placeholder: string
    icon: JSX.Element
    register: UseFormRegisterReturn
    percentage?: boolean
}

export default function InputWrapper(props: InputWrapperProps) {
    const shouldShowDefValue = shouldShowDefaultValue(props.register.name as keyof PlanEngineInputs)
    const defaultValue = String(shouldShowDefValue ? accessNestedObject(defaultTextualInput, props.register.name) : undefined)

    return (
        <FormInput
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            inputLeftElement={cloneElement(props.icon, { color: 'lightgray' })}
            type='number'
            onInput={(e) => globalOnInput(e, props.percentage)}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            {...props.register}
        />
    )
}
```

Here is the `utils` file which is responsible for all the saving and retrieving from local storage:

```
import { PlanEngineInputs } from 'models/retirement-calculator'
import { UseFormSetValue } from 'react-hook-form'
import { modifyNestedPath } from 'utils'

export const rawInputsKey = 'new_plan_inputs_raw'
export const formattedInputsKey = 'new_plan_inputs_formatted'

// IMPORTANT: Percentages are formatted differently as this is a textual input :)
export const defaultTextualInput: PlanEngineInputs = {
    age: 20,
    annualIncome: 70_000,
    annualSpending: 30_000,
    networth: 0,
    withdrawalStrategy: { type: 'DEFAULT', safeWithdrawalRate: 4 },
    inflationRate: 0,
    stocksAllocationRate: 100,
    bondsAllocationRate: 0,
    cashAllocationRate: 0,
    stocksReturnRate: 7,
    bondsReturnRate: 0,
    cashReturnRate: 0,
    maximumAge: 100,
    retirementAge: 70,
    incomeGrowthRate: 0
}

function updateLocalStorage(key: string, inputs: Partial<PlanEngineInputs>): void {
    let prevInputs: Partial<PlanEngineInputs> | null = null

    if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
        prevInputs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)!) as Partial<PlanEngineInputs>
    }

    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({ ...prevInputs, ...inputs }))
}

export function updateFormattedInputs(inputs: Partial<PlanEngineInputs>) {
    updateLocalStorage(formattedInputsKey, inputs)
}

export function updateRawInputs(inputs: Partial<PlanEngineInputs>): void {
    updateLocalStorage(rawInputsKey, inputs)
}

export function loadLocalStorage(reset: UseFormSetValue<Partial<PlanEngineInputs>>): void {
    if (localStorage.getItem(rawInputsKey)) {
        const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(rawInputsKey)!) as Partial<PlanEngineInputs>

        for (const key in item) {
            const asKey = key as keyof Partial<PlanEngineInputs>

            reset(asKey, item[asKey])
        }
    }
}

export function shouldShowDefaultValue(key: keyof PlanEngineInputs): boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem(rawInputsKey)) {
        return (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(rawInputsKey)!) as Partial<PlanEngineInputs>)[key] === undefined
    }

    return true
}

export function globalOnInput(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, percentage: boolean = false): void {
    let newValue = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value)

    if (percentage) {
        newValue /= 100
    }

    if (e.currentTarget.value.split('.').length > 1) {
        updateFormattedInputs(modifyNestedPath({}, e.currentTarget.name, newValue))
    } else {
        updateFormattedInputs({ [e.currentTarget.name]: newValue })
    }
}
```

The big issue I'm having is in the page which is responsible for the `WithdrawalStrategy` inputs. The `WithdrawalStrategy` is a union type, which looks like:

```
export type WithdrawalStrategy = 
    { type: 'DEFAULT', safeWithdrawalRate: number } | 
    { type: 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE', amount: number } | 
    { type: 'FIXED_DOLLAR', amount: number }
```

Here is the form responsible for the withdrawalStrategy inputs:

```
import { Select } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { PlanEngineInputs } from 'models/retirement-calculator'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { MdAttachMoney, MdPercent } from 'react-icons/md'
import InputWrapper from './InputWrapper'
import { defaultTextualInput, loadLocalStorage, updateFormattedInputs, updateRawInputs } from '../utils'
import { modifyNestedPath } from 'utils'

export default function FinancialFactorsInputs() {
    const { register, setValue, watch, unregister } = useForm<Partial<PlanEngineInputs>>()

    const withdrawalStrategyType = watch('withdrawalStrategy.type') || defaultTextualInput.withdrawalStrategy.type

    useEffect(() => {
        loadLocalStorage(setValue)
    }, [])

    watch((inputs, key) => {
        updateRawInputs(inputs as Partial<PlanEngineInputs>)

        if (key.name === 'withdrawalStrategy.type') {
            updateFormattedInputs(inputs as Partial<PlanEngineInputs>)
        }
    })

    function selectChangeHandler(): void {
        // not the cleanest of code, but will do for now
        unregister('withdrawalStrategy.amount')
        unregister('withdrawalStrategy.safeWithdrawalRate')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Select {...register('withdrawalStrategy.type', { onChange: selectChangeHandler })} defaultValue={defaultTextualInput.withdrawalStrategy.type}>
                <option value='DEFAULT'>Default</option>
                <option value='FIXED_PERCENTAGE'>Fixed Percentage</option>
                <option value='FIXED_DOLLAR'>Fixed Dollar</option>
            </Select>

            {(withdrawalStrategyType === 'FIXED_DOLLAR' || withdrawalStrategyType === 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE') && (
                <InputWrapper
                    placeholder='Amount'
                    icon={<MdAttachMoney />}
                    register={register('withdrawalStrategy.amount')}
                />
            )}

            {withdrawalStrategyType === 'DEFAULT' && (
                <InputWrapper
                    placeholder='Safe Withdrawal Rate'
                    icon={<MdPercent />}
                    register={register('withdrawalStrategy.safeWithdrawalRate')}
                    percentage={true}
                />
            )}

            <InputWrapper
                placeholder='Inflation Rate'
                icon={<MdPercent />}
                register={register('inflationRate')}
                percentage={true}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

The issue is, the JSON for the formatted inputs (given a simple demo) is like so:

```
{
    "withdrawalStrategy": {
        "type": "FIXED_PERCENTAGE"
    },
    "withdrawalStrategy.amount": 8
}
```

As you can see, it's not formatted properly, instead it should be formatted like this:

```
    "withdrawalStrategy": {
        "type": "FIXED_PERCENTAGE"
        "amount": 5
    }
```

Specifically, the reason why this is happening is because of this code:

```
    updateFormattedInputs({ [e.currentTarget.name]: newValue })
```

This code works good if an object is one layer deep, but for objects with other objects, `e.currentTarget.name` would just be the path to that object, so it messes everything up.

How can I extend this system to nested objects?